# how to get started with the game developement on PC

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to get started with game development on PC. I heard there are some commercial game engine to facilitate this process. I am wondering anyone can shed some lights on PCgame development. Thanks.

Comment: Come up with an idea, implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good list of engines at the GPWiki (including many which aren't commercial, and so probably easier to get started with), which I'm sure also has a lot of other information.

http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines

I suppose this is also required linking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Comment: For simple chess game, what's your suggestion?

Comment: For a simple chess game, you don't really need a game engine, as those are mainly to handle fast graphics or physics. You would need to know how to program, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your background is, but your best bet will be to learn a programming language and go from there. I started off with QBasic and slowly taught myself the language by building simple games.

You can also learn quite a bit from a site like this: http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml

Maybe a bit of a stretch, but some games come with map editors that are quite powerful and can be used to make their own games. For instance, StarCraft II ships with a very powerful editor that can be used to learn about game development and you won't have to worry about writing an engine.

Comment: I just to want to write some simple chess game on PC, what's your suggestion?

Comment: It really depends what you're looking to do. If its just a programming exercise, then I'd go as simple as possible. Like a grid of buttons on a windows form... similar to minesweeper.